# Try to post array of objects from postman to php api and get errors

Tags: php, postman

I came from Java-Script world and this syntax is strange for me for me.

I try to send post request from postman with body of array of objects like this:

My php code:

```
<?php
$signatures = $_POST["signatures"];
$signature = array_filter($signatures);
echo json_encode($signature);
```

But my response from postman is:

[image]

Comment: `signatures[]` without the index, and dict values don't have `[]` at all

Comment: still not work @HagaiWild

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing this is impossible I assume, you can only transfer strings using `POST` and `GET`, try to send all the data in just one `KEY` and then `json_decode` it in serve side. So try to send something like this

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "flowID": 1,
    "fileID": 1,
    "type": "partner",
    "page": 1
  }
]
```

as `VALUE`, with `KEY`: `signatures`, then in PHP code:

```
<?php
$signatures = json_decode($_POST["signatures"]); // <=== this is an array now
print_r($signature);
```

Comment: I try this with application/json and urlencoded and its not work.

Comment: Probably you are not doing it properly, my colleague (a mobile-app developer) and I developed some apps by this method, it's better to debug that part then, I think this is the best practice.

Comment: You send the array on application/json ?

Comment: @WebDeveloper No.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to filter an array but you did not written how to filter it (second parameter)

```
    <?php
$signatures = $_POST["signatures"];
$signature = array_filter($signatures,<**variabile or function to be filtered**>);
echo json_encode($signature);
```

Comment: I still not understand what is the second parameter? why i need him? i just want to get the body of the post.

Answer (score 0):

How to send array of objects:
Set postman to application/json and post body:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "flowID": 1,
        "fileID": 2,
        "type": "identification",
        "page": 1,
        "positionX": 160,
        "positionY": 241,
        "sizeWidth": 150,
        "sizeHeight": 250
    },
        {
        "id": 2,
        "flowID": 4,
        "fileID": 2,
        "type": "partner",
        "page": 1,
        "positionX": 160,
        "positionY": 241,
        "sizeWidth": 150,
        "sizeHeight": 250
    }
]
```

Get the request body and make it array:

```
$rawPostBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
$signatures = (array)json_decode($rawPostBody);
```

Loop over the array:

```
foreach($signatures as $signature) {
    echo $signature->type;
}
```

Hope this helps those who ever look for how to do it.